# How can I get a method from an installed bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, methods, bundle

Like this I created a method to get an array of the Ids of my category bundle:

```
class Event
{  

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Bundle\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category")
     */
    private $categories;


   /**
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty()
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("categories")
     */
    public function getCategories(): ?array
    {   

        if($this->categories != NULL){
            return $this->categories->map(fn($a) => $a->getId())->toArray();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But instead if "id" I try to get the "name". So I simply try to change this line:

```
return $this->categories->map(fn($a) => $a->getName())->toArray();
```

But I get the error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getName" of class
> "Bundle\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category".

Did I need to join name field before?

Comment: Did you look into your Category entity and is there a getName method ?

Comment: I do not know how to get access to the bundle.

Comment: is it a local bundle ? Added from composer so in `/vendor` ? If you use phpstorm or a well configured vscode you could just ctrl + click on `targetEntity="Bundle\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category"`